# Were the veth's spells per day and spells known ever corrected?

Tags: prestige-class, dnd-3e, greyhawk

While digging through and compiling aging material, I happened upon the Greyhawk-specific prestige class [veth](https://web.archive.org/web/20050312042011/http://www.wizards.com:80/default.asp?x=lg/articles/20030610vetha) (link is to the *Internet Archive* version; the original apparently gone). The class appeared originally in the *Living Greyhawk Journal* #2 and was republished on the Wizards of the Coast Web site, [it seems](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/d20worldofgreyhawk/rhenee-and-living-greyhawk-journal-for-gm-consider-t1028.html), warts and all.

*Anyway.* Regarding its spells, the prestige class's text and table conflict *and* its two tables conflict with *each other*. Were adjustments—perhaps in print in some Living Greyhawk material—ever made to this prestige class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not really possible to prove a negative, I am going to state that no, they never published an errata for the veth prestige class. I spent a long time going through various links on archive.org as well as numerous discussion forums and wiki related pages. There were some fan created corrected tables, but there were no official references, and more telling, there were no discussion posts stating that any errata was ever published for this.

Sources viewed:

- ENWorld (No relevant results)
- RPGNet (No relevant results)
- Archive.org ([Living Greyhawk](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=lg/articles/20030610vetha) (2005, last intact race page), discussion forums [searches for veth, vetha, living greyhawk, errata in singuler/various combos], notices, errata pages)
- Greyhawk Online - [User created errata summary](http://www.greyhawkonline.com/grodog/gh_errata.html), no mention of veth
- BoardGameGeek (No relevant results)
- Reddit (Multiple, no relevant results. A little hard to search as Veth was a name of a Greyhawk character as well)
- D&D Beyond (No results of searches)
- [moam.info](https://moam.info/living-greyhawk-campaign-sourcebook-meetup_59ddc08b1723dd7d9b812bb6.html) - Uncertain legality - Online PDF of a Living Greyhawk campaign sourcebook - Info on how to update veth to 3.5, no other corrections
- [Tapatalk](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/d20worldofgreyhawk/rhenee-and-living-greyhawk-journal-for-gm-consider-t1028.html) - Acknowledges and changes the errored charts - Only writeup I found that acknowledged and made the corrections)
- Various Wiki style pages

Comment: @HeyICanChan - I had already closed the browser, but I went through and recreated the relevant finds.

Comment: I think the Giant in the Playground forums are also pretty relevant to 3.x-era D&D—they also [don’t have anything on this prestige class](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agiantitp.com+%22veth%22&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). The Min/Max Boards also [have nothing](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aminmaxforum.com%2F+%22veth%22&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).